# PySpark Linear Regression in dataset with more features than data points

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using PySpark to develop a simple text mining application. The goal is to classify a specific document as Spam or Not Spam. I have approximately 1000 documents available to train the model (**n**).

After cleaning the data (orthographic error correction, stemming, etc) I use IDF to extract a features vector. By default the feature dimension of this vectorization method is 2^18=262144, meaning that I'll have a total of 262144 highly sparse features (**p**).

Considering that **p >> n**:

As I remember, and according to some articles and web-articles I found, it's not possible to apply a Linear Regression with this type of data without doing any feature reduction, otherwise the algorithm would **fail** (because with p > n the variance would be infinite).

To test this I ran a Linear Regression on my data:

```
...

idf_stage = IDF(inputCol=hashingTF.getOutputCol(), outputCol="features", minDocFreq=1)
lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, tol=1E-6)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[..., idf_stage, lr])

model = pipeline.fit(train)
results = model.transform(test)
results.select("label", "prediction").show()
```

And I got the following results:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|label|          prediction|
+-----+--------------------+
|  1.0|  0.8123660495998272|
|  1.0|  0.9485273761704205|
|  0.0| 0.25039087467730653|
|  1.0|  1.2359878831283708|
|  0.0|-0.14295806192187976|
|            ...           |
+-----+--------------------+
```

I was expecting this to fail so it surprised me when I noticed that no exception was thrown.

There are a couple of things I can't figure out:

**Question 1:** When it's said that a Linear Regression algorithm will fail when p > n what is the meaning of fail? Should it not work at all and throw an exception or should it run but return results that shouldn't be considered?

**Question 2:** If the algorithm should throw an exception why is it running? Is Spark doing any feature reduction behind the scenes?

**Question 3:** Since Logistic Regression can be turned into a Linear Regression problem using variable transformations does it present the same problems when p > n?

Comment: Cross-site almost dupe: [Why is it the case that when we try to fit an OLS model to a system with more variables than observations, that the residuals are zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135163/why-is-it-the-case-that-when-we-try-to-fit-an-ols-model-to-a-system-with-more-va)

Comment: By default Spark doesn't use use closed form solution if number of features exceeds `LinearRegression.MAX_FEATURES_FOR_NORMAL_SOLVER` (4096). Instead it treats it as an optimization problem, and solves it using limited memory gradient descent to optimize cost function. There is no reason for it to fail, though solution doesn't have to be precise. Same as a many packages don't use actual inverse,  and instead apply [pseudoinverese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse), and can reach a solution, even if T(X) * X is not reversible.

Comment: @user10465355 your answer actually answered the question- you didn't need to delete and convert to a comment. Either way it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

A failure would be expected only if you used closed form solution:

(X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> y

and additional verification was applied.

However this is not the only approach that can be used, and not a one that is normally used in Spark. It is possible to use numerical methods, like

- Using [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse). This is how linear is usually implemented in different packages.
- Iterative optimization procedures including different variants of gradient descent.

and can be used even if  (X<sup>T</sup> X) non-invertible or ill-condition. There is of course no guarantee that these result in any sensible solution.

By default `o.a.s.ml.regression.LinearRegression` uses closed form solution (["normal" solver](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L273-L274)) only if the number of features is lower than 4096 (It is a default value of [`LinearRegression.MAX_FEATURES_FOR_NORMAL_SOLVER`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/optim/WeightedLeastSquares.scala#L333)).